# Permission Denied for gacutil in linux

Tags: linux, apache, mono, centos, gacutil

I have the `Mono gacutil` on a Linux machine, CentOS 5.5, apache 2.2. I'm running as the root user. I keep getting

> /usr/local/bin/gacutil: line 2: /usr/local/bin/mono: Permission denied

This is with any command from `gacutil`, like `-l` or `-i`. Putting sudo in front gives the same message.

Any ideas?

EDIT: ls -l /usr/local/bin/mono gives me this:

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8629697

EDIT2:

> There's no executable bit set on that file. It's giving you a permission denied because it's not executable.

I guess the question turns into this: I think gacutil is looking in the wrong place for the GAC. How can I change what folder it looks into?

Comment: What does `ls -l /usr/local/bin/mono` tell you?

Comment: sudo only works if you have appropriate permission in /etc/sudoers file

Comment: There's no executable bit set on that file. It's giving you a permission denied because it's not executable.